# rounding autoSumForm values

Tags: javascript

I have searched for a few days now trying to find a solution. I have looked at the php.net info, but it seems to be in a different format to my code below. Please could someone show me how to round this sort of calculation. Thank you

```
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value = ((one*20) + (110*20))/17;
three = document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value;
  four = document.autoSumForm.fourthBox.value = ((three*20) + (150*20))/17;
five = document.autoSumForm.fifthBox.value;
  six = document.autoSumForm.sixthBox.value = ((five*20) + (250*20))/17;
  seven = document.autoSumForm.seventhBox.value = (four*1) - (two*1);
eight = document.autoSumForm.eigthBox.value = (six*1) - (two*1);
}

function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not PHP. Which language are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to this and learning as I go. I guess I need the solution for JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: Then take a look at [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#Methods). Also, this interval method is quite "unfriendly" for browsers. Try another solution, e.g. binding `onchange` event of those boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked :). I will look into making it more "friendly". I will have to learn a bit more first.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your code is in Javascript, not PHP. Also, this isn't cross-platform Javascript either.

You're better off doing something like this:

```
document.forms['autoSumForm'].elements['firstBox'].value
```

You could use a library like jQuery to make this a little easier and more readable, but if this is as complex as it gets, a large library like jQuery may be overkill.